# How to configure Tailwind CSS and material-tailwind in the same tailwind.config.js file

Tags: javascript, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css, next.js13

I want to use Tailwind and Material Tailwind together in a Next.js 14 project.

This is my **tailwind.config.ts** file (already setup with Tailwind css):

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;
```

According to the material-tailwind (https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/guide/next) documentation, we have to add this code to **tailwind.config.ts**

> **TailwindCSS Configurations**
>
> Once you install @material-tailwind/react you need to wrap your tailwind css configurations with the withMT() function coming from @material-tailwind/react/utils on the tailwind.config.js file:

```
const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");
 
module.exports = withMT({
  content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
})
```

Then I changed the **tailwind.config.ts** file like this:

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'
const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");

module.exports = withMT({
  content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
});

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;
```

My problem is there are no compiling errors, but it only works **material-tailwind**. Tailwind css not working. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to wrap *your* configuration with the `withMT()` function, like:

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'
import withMT from '@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT';

const config: Config = withMT({
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
});
export default config;
```

Types and the real `import` member may need adjusting to actually work, but this should illustrate the point.

Comment: Thank You !!!
But when I added like `import withMT from "@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT";` got an error ***[Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'Config'.
  Property 'content' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'RequiredConfig'.ts(2322)
config.d.ts(348, 3): 'content' is declared here.]*** then I changed it like this `const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");`

Comment: problem is the same some CSS parts not working